# redirect to a dedicated sign in page

Tags: wp-admin, wp-redirect

I am creating a plugin to redirect all sign in attempts to a dedicated page rather than using the builting wordpress page
so i created this hook action for the admin_init with the highest priority over other callbacks

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'redirect_callback', 1)
```

the callback function will then make sure the user is not signed in already to make the redirect

```
function redirect_callback() {
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
      wp_redirect( /* my link */ );
      exit;
    }
}
```

and of course the `is_user_logged_in()` needs this dependency

```
include(ABSPATH."wp-includes/pluggable.php")
```

visiting this link: `url/wp-admin` still doesn't redirect anywhere, it still pulls up the wordpress press sign in page.
anyone can help ?

Comment: I think the template_redirect hook (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_redirect/) should fit better to what you try to accomplish.

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. I hope you find the answer(s) you are looking for. Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work.

Answer (score 0):

this line did the task perfectly

```
add_filter( 'login_url', function(){return /* the custom URL */;});
```

here is the explanation:(valid for **wordpress 5.4.1**)
by the time admin_init fires, it's too late already.
once `url/wp-admin` is visited, index.php launches first
then requires `admin.php` (line 10)
then the file will execute `94. auth_redirect();`
before `170. do_action( 'admin_init' );`

[auth_redirect()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/auth_redirect/) core function uses [wp_login_url()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_login_url/)
which in its turn uses [login_url](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/login_url/), as indicated in the wordpress documentation plage.  we can apply a filter to it with any URL we like.

Answer (score 0):

So I add an action to call the function:

// Redirect anyone from the wp-login screen to the custom distributor login

```
add_action('init','custom_login');
```

Then I create a function to direct to custom url:

```
function custom_login(){  
   global $pagenow;  
   if( 'wp-login.php' == $pagenow && $_GET['action']!="logout") {  
     wp_redirect('https://example.com/new_login/');  
   }  
}
```

Comment: thank you for your contribution but there is an "exit;" missing after the redirect, because wp_redirect doesnt exit automatically.